# Bootstrap 3 Tabs Data only showing on first tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm using the Bootstrap 3 tabs and accordion within the tabs.

The html I currently have is the following:

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#1270013" aria-controls="#1270013" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">DF</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#1270015" aria-controls="#1270015" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">HWR</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-panel active" id="1270013">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion3" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading30">
                        <h4 class="panel-title"><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" href="#collapse30" aria-expanded="true" aria-control="collapse30">2015-10-14 13:36:34</a></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse30" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading30">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                           ...
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading31">
                        <h4 class="panel-title"><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" href="#collapse31" aria-expanded="true" aria-control="collapse31">2015-10-14 11:46:26</a></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse31" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading31">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                        ...
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading31">
                        <h4 class="panel-title"><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" href="#collapse31" aria-expanded="true" aria-control="collapse31">2015-10-14 11:46:26</a></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse31" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading31">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            ...
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading32">
                        <h4 class="panel-title"><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" href="#collapse32" aria-expanded="true" aria-control="collapse32">2015-10-14 09:56:14</a></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse32" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading32">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            ...
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-panel" id="1270015">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion5" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading50">
                        <h4 class="panel-title"><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion5" href="#collapse50" aria-expanded="true" aria-control="collapse50">2015-10-14 14:08:31</a></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse50" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading50">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            ...
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now this code displays the 2 tabs above, but the data from the second tab will be shown beneath the first tab data.

I can't find the mistake I made why the second tab data won't show in the second tab instead in the first one.

I'm using jQuery 1.9.1 and the current Bootstrap 3 version.

Also I don't have any own written JavaScript, I worked with the data tags within the HTML.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s9s5m3n3/)

Comment: add your code jsfiddle

Comment: @LaljiTadhani updated my question with a full working example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change Your Class name

1st tab Content

```
tab-pane fade in active
```

2nd tab Content

```
tab-pane fade
```

Demo link  http://jsfiddle.net/s9s5m3n3/2/

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine

change the class name of inside content tab `.tab-panel` to `.tab-pane` for both `#1270013` and `#1270015`

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sachinkk/s9s5m3n3/3/